# Use StAX parse RPC style soap response

Tags: xml, parsing, soap

I have a soap response which is RPC style, so it has 'multiref's. The response was passed to me as a String. Can I use StAX parser to parse it? Can StaX resolve mutirefs automatically?

Thanks,

Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, multi-refs are a feature of the SOAP encoding model, and not a feature of xml itself. You'll have to decode the multi-refs yourself either after you've finished xml parsing (easier but requires you to save a lot of state), or as you go (which can be more efficient, but still require a lot of state, and a lot of work). Unless you're dealing with large documents you may just be better giving up on streaming parse and use a DOM style parer. then at least you can fairly easily xpath through the doc to resolve the references.
The other option of course, it to find a soap toolkit that can parse it for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question superfell. I end up writing a class to resolve the multiRefs so the input to StAx parser is 'plain'xml. I could've used DOM style parser, but in my situation is we've alreday writen StAx parsing and anticipating document style soap response, but end up getting RPC style!